# Why is the Stack Exchange Podcast no longer available in the iTunes Store?

Tags: support, podcast

iTunes has just started telling me the blog.stackexchange.com/feed/podcast is unavailable so it can no longer find any podcasts. (In fact no updates since June).

When I search for Stack Exchange Podcast in the Apple Store some old episodes are listed but when I click the link to "The Stack Exchange Podcoast" I'm told it is no longer available in my country.

Have I missed something here? (I'm a bit old school, I still just use iTunes and sync with my old iPod Classic).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The podcast feed was an unforeseen casualty when the blog was updated to its [shiny new iteration](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/07/the-new-stack-exchange-blog/). This issue was fixed in the usual six to eight weeks, however that was long enough for the podcast to fall out of the iTunes store. It's back now.

As you were already subscribed your podcast player should automatically redirect to the new feed and start picking up new, and missed episodes. But, if needed, **the canonical URL for the podcast feed is: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/podcast/** as per [Abby's official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264230/281117).

Note: It's possible to manually subscribe to a podcast in iTunes without finding that podcast in the iTunes store. You can enter the url with `File -> Subscribe to podcast...` (or `Advanced -> Subscribe to podcast...` for older versions of iTunes).