# Podcast download possible?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, podcast

Is it no longer possible to download podcasts as mp3 ?

Even with all my pop-up, ad, and tracker blockers turned off I can no longer see any download button on the blog.so site or soundcloud.

There are workarounds to download a stream from Soundcloud of course - but I seem to remember some other Q&A site where you had to use all sorts of tricks to access the content without signing up to yet another "if you aren't paying=you are the product" type site.

edit: Ok so it's just incompetence not an attempt to block out us uncool kids who don't have permanent streaming of our mySpaces to our iPhones?

Comment: Did you find [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263731/why-is-the-stack-exchange-podcast-no-longer-available-in-australia/264272#264272)?

Comment: Does that only apply to Australia and iTunes? 
The workaround  still doesn't give a link to the actual file

Comment: Did you find this url: http://blog.stackexchange.com/feed/podcast/

Comment: I can download the [mp3](http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/223184390-stack-exchange-stack-exchange-podcast-episode-68-a-badger-a-horse-and-a-dik-dik-the-documentation-episode.mp3) that is found in that feed

Comment: Is it a rss feed? . My browser opens it as an xml file

Comment: Yeah, that is the rss feed. IE11 handles that for me...

Comment: As the person in charge of such things, I can say with certainty that this boiled down to simple incompetence, not malice :)

Comment: @abbyhairboat, many thanks. Back when Joel+Jeff were a struggling start-up and worked hard to produce a weekly podcast it deserved a slot on my phone. Now that they are both millionaire playboys with only an occasional offering I have to rely on cruising past the blog ;-)

Comment: The podcasts are now on soundcast. I don't see an obvious way to download them but if one is so inclined  , this could/should be a new question rather than building on a question's from multiple blog incarnations ago. As such I am closing this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange) has a download button for all podcasts <s>except for the latest ([#68](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/stack-exchange-podcast-68-a-badger-a-horse-and-a-dik-dik-the-documentation-episode/)), which was presumably an oversight. [You can download episode 68 here](http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/223184390-stack-exchange-stack-exchange-podcast-episode-68-a-badger-a-horse-and-a-dik-dik-the-documentation-episode.mp3)</s>.

If you don't wish to subscribe to the podcast directly with a podcast player, subscribing to the [feed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/podcast/) with your favourite RSS reader should allow you to download the podcast episodes.

I've submitted a pull-request which would add download links to the podcast posts on the blog, please allow 6-8 weeks for delivery.

Comment: I've fixed the SoundCloud download link for podcast #68 as well.